# Xcode 6 UIVisualEffectView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, ios8, xcode6

I am looking around the Object Library in Xcode 6 for UIVisualEffectView to add a blur in Storyboard. I know how to do this programmatically, but I can't find a way to do this in the Storyboard.

Is this unavailable in the current beta, or is there a way to do this that is not so straightforward?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**iOS 8.0 Gold Master UPDATE**

As of the iOS 8.0 Gold Master, Xcode now has a UIVisualEffectView available in the Objects Library. To add a UIVisualEffectView to your Storyboard, just drag it from the Objects Library, position it, and then customize it using the attributes inspector.

---

**iOS 8.0 Beta 5 and Earlier**

To add a `UIVisualEffectView` in a Storyboard follow these steps:

1. Create a regular, empty UIView (from the objects library)
2. Set the custom class of the UIView to `UIVisualEffectView`:
   [image]
3. Connect this new view to your code, make sure that you do not add any subviews directly to it in the Storyboard (as noted in Apple's documentation).
4. Proceed with the programmatic setup (i.e. with the `contentView`).

Unfortunately, it looks like the `contentView` property is not an IBOutlet and therefore cannot be set in the interface (at least in this beta). Hopefully they will change that in the next beta. I filed a bug report with Apple to be able to create a UIVisualEffectView completely in Storyboards ([Open Radar](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4993609896034304) for rdar://17742263).

---

**iOS 8.0 Beta 5 and Earlier - EDIT**

While you are able to add a `UIVisualEffectView` to a Storyboard using the method described above, it is not possible to initialize that view from the Storyboard. In the current beta (iOS 8, Beta 3) these views should be created programmatically for any effect at all.

The [UIVisualEffects GitHub Repo](https://github.com/ide/UIVisualEffects) demonstrates an easy way to setup and use the new API in a variety of ways (repo is only in Swift though, no Objective-C code).

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can give it a UIBlurEffect or UIVibrancyEffect yet in this beta as far as you can see, right? It doesn't do much good unless those are available. Keep this post updated if you can with whatever progress the radar has. If they even read it ;]

Comment: @erdekhayser You're correct! Unfortunately, Apple does not provide alternative `init` methods (just that one for programmatic setup). The radar link has been added and is available on OpenRadar. Fingers Crossed for a fix in Seed 4!

Comment: I think GM includes this (did not check in later betas). I'll let you edit your answer if you want

Comment: Unfortunately, the UIVisualEffectView disappeared in Xcode 6.3 beta 1.